# How to find whats using network traffic

Tags: linux, redhat

What tool can I use to figure out what process is using the network over a certain time frame and how much data was transferred?

I can tell the data is transferred over a 5 minute period.  Could be a backup.  Is the process the right thing to be looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *nethogs* to exactly to that.

> sudo yum -y install nethogs

To run nethogs:

> sudo nethogs

To monitor your network you could also use *iftop* to monitor during your transfer, you'll see hosts you're communicating with. current, peak, cummulative transfer rates. You however won't be able to see which process.

> sudo yum -y install iftop

If it says you don't have the permissions run it with sudo.

> sudo iftop

To run iftop on a specific interface:

> sudo iftop -i eth0

Comment: The question was what processes are using the network.  iftop shows bandwidth by interface, but I don't think it show it by process.

Comment: You are right, but now I remember of nethogs which can do that. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Great thanks.  I was looking to monitor the process because of the time the transfer happens.  But iftop will sort the issue for me also, Ill just have to stay up.  Unless there is some way to capture the output?

Comment: Check that out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702980/capture-nethogs-output-in-log-file

Comment: But these don't tell each process which server is communicating to...

Answer (score 4):

[nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) shows network usage by process, sorted by highest usage first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [nettop](http://nettop.youlink.org), shows not only usage by process, but even which hostnames you send/receive data, and the split between TCP/UDP traffic. Additionally supports all IPv4 and IPv6 traffic (TCP/UDP only though).